# Axis Ip cameras python API / implementation of rectification?

Tags: python-3.x, video-processing, ros, ip-camera, vapix

I want to receive a rectified image or rectify a image from a Axis IP camera.
I have found a ros distribution https://github.com/ros-drivers/axis_camera
which can do this.

But Im unaware of how I can use this on an ubuntu PC. Tried to make it and failed.

I'd like to know if anyone know of an python API That I can use to download the camera parameters or rectify these parameters.

I see that they provide VAPIX API but I have not found how I can download these camera parameters and how its stored.
Any info is appreciated.